# Cubic bezier and cubic hermite interpolation for FCurves

Tags: python, animation, scripting, bezier-curves, interpolation

I am writing a custom import/export addon for a model file format that supports animations for cameras with cubic hermite and cubic bezier interpolation. Is it somehow possible to emulate the same interpolation effect using Blender's FCurves which appear to only support quadric bezier interpolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender also supports cubic (3rd order) curves.

Hermite curves can be converted into Bézier curves with a bit of math. From the two control points and the derivative at those points you can compute the two other points to complete the Bézier curve. More info can be found at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#catmullconv

Comment: Do you mean that it supports cubic bezier for FCurves in Graph Editor? I don't see that option. When I turn on bezier interpolation, those curves look quadric to me.

Comment: With a quadratic curve, the 'outgoing' slope of one point also determines the 'incoming' slope of the next point. Since the slopes of the points are independent, it follows that the curves are (at least) cubic. You don't see the option because there is no "on" or "off" for this; the Bézier curves are always cubic.